# How to resolve NopCommerce Error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nopcommerce

In Product display page showing **proper image** but when I click any product Image it is throw bellow **error**.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1061:
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper'
>   does not contain a definition for 'GenerateCaptcha' and no extension
>   method 'GenerateCaptcha' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

```
Source Error:


Line 47:                 {
Line 48:                     <div class="captcha-box">
Line 49:                         @Html.Raw(Html.GenerateCaptcha())
Line 50:                     </div>
Line 51:                 }

Source File: h:\root\home\raaisoma-001\www\site1\Plugins\SevenSpikes.Nop.Plugins.NopQuickTabs\Views\ProductTab\_ProductReviews.cshtml    Line: 49
```

But When I click on **QuickView** product display properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing appropaite namespace. Add

```
using Nop.Web.Framework.UI.Captcha;
```

to this file